# What does the index variable k define in the Lasso regularization function

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

In the Lasso L1 regularization, from where comes the value of the variable $k$ in the second part of the function? Why isn't it $n$, too?

$$L(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \phi(x_i)^T \cdot \beta)^2 + \lambda \sum_{j = 1}^k l(\beta_j)$$

$\beta$ is the parameter vector, $y$ the output vector and $x$ the input vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$k$ is the length of $\beta$, the number of coefficients.  The penalty is a function of the coefficients, not of the data.

Note, however, as a minor point, that you don't have to apply the penalty to all the coefficients in the model, although in your formulation you are.

Comment: Right, I thought the dimension for instance $\beta$ and $y$ have to be the same, that's why I had the confusion.

Comment: (+1) In particular, if you happen to not be using centered predictors and you do have an intercept in the model, you probably don't want to include it in the penalization.